# getting specific data from jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting all the records from jqgrid but I need to get data for only non-hidden/visible columns/colmodels. I am using this to get the data and which is rendering all the data  `$("#parentID").jqGrid('getGridParam')`, so my question is how do I exclude hidden data and get only visible data. I tried looping through `colmodels` and then check if it's hidden or not but still I am getting all the data. I have included some code for more clarification. Please help on this issue

```js
var result;
//I created a loop
var colMod = $("#TestT").jqGrid('
    //CHECK FOR HIDDEN OR NOT 
    for (i = 0; i < colMod.length; i++) {

      if (!colMod[i]['hidden']) {
        result = $("#parentID").jqGrid('getGridParam'); //I have a condition here to check for hidden or not but still i am getting all the data from grid. how can i only get non hidden data here?
      }
    }
```

```js
colNames: ['ID', 'NAME', 'Section'],
  colModel: [{
      name: 'ID',
      index: 'ID',
      width: 75,
    }
  }
}, {
  name: 'NAME',
  index: 'NAME',
  width: 60
}, {
  name: 'Section',
  index: 'TEST1',
  width: 40,
  hidden: true
},
} //this is hidden so do not include this
```

Comment: somehow I could not edit my code , there is an incomplete line right before for loop. should be : var colMod = $("#TestT").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');